# How to match a string not containing a word?

Tags: perl

Say I have this input:

```
Printer: A
Some other lines.
Status: good
Printer: B
Some other lines.
Status: bad
```

I want to use one match to get the printer name in bad status, 'B' in this case. How do I do it? I have tried a few but I kept getting both names. For example:

```
$ perl -e 'undef $/; $_=<>; /^Printer: (?:\n|.)+?^Status: bad$/; print' input

Printer: A
Some other lines.
Status: good
Printer: B
Some other lines.
Status: bad
```

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the input a filehandle? An array of lines? A single string?

Comment: mkHun, added. ysth, a file or a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    undef $/;
$_=<DATA>;
if($_=~/Printer:\s+([^\n]+)((?:(?!Status:\s+[\w]+)(?!Printer:\s+\1).)*?)(Status:\s+bad\b)/si){
  print "Result: $1";
}

__DATA__
Printer: A
Some other lines.
Status: good
Printer: C
Some other lines.
Status: badboy
Printer: B
Some other lines.
Status: bad
Printer: D
Status: better
```

Comment: try explaining how this fixes the OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a input file. Try this:

```
my $preline;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    if (/^Status: Bad/)
    {
        my $printer = $preline, scalar <>;
        $printer =~ m/^Printer:\s+(.*)/;
        print "$1\n";
        last;
    }
    $preline = $_;
}
```

Output:

```
B
```

Comment: What if there are some other lines between Status and Printer?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably tackle the problem like this:

- Select printer and status into a hash, using a regexp and map.
- Filter the results, looking for a particular key.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper; 

#traverse all of <DATA> extracting pairs of values, that make hash keys. 
my %printer_status = map { m/(?:Printer|Status): (\w+)/ } <>; 
#for debug, print
print Dumper \%printer_status; 

#print the keys of that hash that are 'bad'. 
print join "\n", grep { $printer_status{$_} eq "bad" } keys %printer_status;
```

Now, this is written out in a longer form for illustrative purposes - note, it assumes that the ordering of 'Printer' and 'Status' is consistent, and there's no dupes. (Of either key or value).

This either reads piped data from `STDIN` or a file specified as an argument. Given your example this prints:

```
B
```

Now, as you say you want a one liner that condenses down to:

```
perl -e '%p=map {m/(?:Printer|Status): (\w+)/}<>; print join "\n", grep {$p{$_} eq "bad"} keys %p'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
#!perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $printerName = "";
while (<DATA>) {
  if (/Printer: (\w+)/) {
    $printerName = $1;
    next;
  }
  if (/Status: (\w+)/){
    my $status = $1;
    print "$printerName, $status\n" if ($status =~ /bad/i);
    next;
  }
}

__DATA__
Printer: A
Some other lines.
Some more other lines.
Status: good
Printer: B
Some other lines.
another line
yet another line
Status: bad
```